# Clojure proxy and @Override?

Tags: clojure

In Java when you want to override something you use @Override sometimes. How can you do the same in a Clojure proxy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every method in a proxy should override a superclass method or an interface method, so it's a slightly different situation from a Java class where you can add new methods. So, if Clojure offered a way to mark proxy methods as overrides, then all valid proxies would have that annotation for each method.

Unfortunately, Clojure will let you define a method in a proxy that does not belong to any of the classes or interfaces that the proxy overrides. That method will not be callable or accessible in normal usage, however.

Comment: No: you cant make sure to override an existing method using proxy like using java @Override annotations: (proxy [Object] [] (nonExistingBaseMethod [] "Foo"))

Comment: The comment is correct and the answer wrong. The purpose of @Override is to provide a check that the method so annotated is in fact overriding a existing method as intended rather than accidentally declaring a new method. `proxy` provides no such safeguard.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain why Clojure doesn't have the annotation (every method in the proxy would have it), and also pointing out that it doesn't prevent you from defining functions that don't override anything.